# Service Worker 'inactive' event

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

Basically within the Service Worker, I'm storing data using the chrome.storage API

Currently, I'm using `visibilitychange` to store the data, but was wondering if there is an event listener, or some sort of technique, to detect when the Service Worker is about to become inactive, for efficiency purposes

Comment: There's no such event. There's also no `visibilitychange` event inside service worker because it's invisible. What kind of problem are you solving - are you writing a lot of megabytes many times a second?

Comment: @wOxxOm I'm using 'visibilitychange' in another JS file (let's just call it 'a.js' for now), and then sending a message from 'a.js' to the Service Worker, commanding it to save an object to storage. It's currently writing around 17kb

Comment: However with what I'm developing, at the end of it, it's probably going to reach around 5mb or even more

Comment: Why don't you use chrome.storage directly in the page? If it's not the `action` popup it'll fire beforeunload event.

Comment: @wOxxOm Can't use it directly in the page unfortunately because I'm using an offscreen document which uses messaging to send data to the service worker when the actual popup is off, and the data from there needs to be saved into storage

Comment: The offscreen document lifetime is not limited (currently) so the only thing you need to worry about is that the extension crashes or the user disables it or the browser exits/crashes. If the data is important you should write it immediately regardless of worsening the performance. BTW you should only worry if the measurements show there's an observable slowdown.

Comment: @wOxxOm The offscreen document's lifetime is limited for me unfortunately since I'm using it for audio playback (becomes inactive after 30 secs if the music is paused or the volume is at 0), but regardless I guess I'll try doing something in it to get it to accurately save the data

Comment: Well you can specify a different reason for the document if the primary purpose is actually storage.

Comment: @wOxxOm it isn't unfortunately. Its primary purpose is to allow audio to play in the background. Data such as the music player's current time needs to be saved into storage when the popup isn't available